# Create and fill gridcontrol at runtime

Tags: devexpress

I have a project in winform with various forms within a form I need to create a popup for clicking a button appears the popup and within this create at runtime one GridControl and fill a datatable previously created. When I do this the GridControl appears empty, what can I do?

here I leave the code

```
        ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
        popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;

        Inventario_MediosDataSet.MedioDataTable m = new Inventario_MediosDataSet.MedioDataTable();
        this.medioTableAdapter1.Fill(m);
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl ki = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl();
        DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView grid = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(ki);
        ki.DataSource = m;
        ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(ki);
        host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
        host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
        popup.Items.Add(host);
        popup.Show(this, simpleButton7.Location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToolStripControlHost does not provide BindingContext for the Grid. You can see the same behavior with DataGridView as well. To resolve the issue, set GridControl.BindingContext to your form BindingContext.

```
ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
popup.Margin = Padding.Empty;
popup.Padding = Padding.Empty;
Inventario_MediosDataSet.MedioDataTable m = new Inventario_MediosDataSet.MedioDataTable();
this.medioTableAdapter1.Fill(m);
DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl ki = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl();
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView grid = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(ki);
ki.MainView = grid;
// --------------------
ki.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
// --------------------
ki.DataSource = m;
ToolStripControlHost host = new ToolStripControlHost(ki);
host.Margin = Padding.Empty;
host.Padding = Padding.Empty;
popup.Items.Add(host);
popup.Show(this, simpleButton1.Location);
```

Comment: @LecsyOlivera If it works for me, mark my answer as a solution to close this issue,